# how to do speaker identification using voice?

Tags: python, voice-recognition

I was wondering if you can detect s using their voice. For example, we give feed some data in our program like this is the voice of a cat and when it detects it, it says hello cat or something.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Machine learning can do that, I suggest using deep-learning such as CNN, LSTM model, etc. what you need to prepare is the dataset of your cat voices and accurate model architecture.

**roughly process**

> 1. prepare dataset:
>
>    - for example: 300 audio files each contain 3 seconds of different cat voices.
> 2. train model
> 3. model evaluation
> 4. script to respond to the output of model classification.
>
>    - say "hello cat" when the prediction output is a cat.

but it's not that easy, hope this example is helpful.
more detail: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2022/03/implementing-audio-classification-project-using-deep-learning/

Comment: I was actually trying to detect specific objects in a game, when an object(avatar) is deployed, it makes a certain sound everytime. Like queen makes the sound("i am the queen)") so dataset will be a lot less. Would that create a problem?

Answer (score 0):

of course, you can use machine learning to solve that problem, you can either deal with it as a signal processing/time series-ish problem and slide a window over your audio then feed it to your model to classify it (cat, dog, ...) LSTMs and RNNs are your go-to in this case. Or transform your audios to spectrogram to transform it into an image, then feed those images to your typical CNN architecture (NASNet, DenseNet, ...).

here is a reference you can check:

- UrbanSound (audio/signal):https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/raghavrawat/segregatedurban8ksounds
- UrbanSound (Spectrogram, I create it long ago): https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/skywolfmo/urban8kspectograms

There might be other ideas and methods besides the ones I mentioned above.

Good luck